# Is it possible to login skype through VB.Net windows application

Tags: vb.net, skype

I want to develop a skype integrated application. For this i am  using Skype4Com.dll.But i don't see any method to log into skype through code.Is it possible to log into skype through VB.Net windows application.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is possible.  I know you are using VB.NET, but here is a FULL working example written in C# that you could adapt:

http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=142821

Basically, you would need to download the source, find how to log in and convert it to VB.NET.  If you aren't very familiar with C# to VB.NET conversion, you could use an online converter that will get you most of the way there if not all the way there.  For example, this site works very well:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/